# RxKotlin repo gradle build compilation fails with gradle 4.7 (JDK 1.8)

Tags: kotlin, rx-kotlin, rx-kotlin2

I tried the following:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin.git    
$ cd RxKotlin/    
$ gradle build
```

It fails with:

> ...FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file '/home/myuser/RxKotlin/build.gradle' line: 13
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'rxkotlin'.
>
>   > org/gradle/api/internal/project/AbstractProject

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have to use the gradle 2.14 version that came as part of the repo instead of the one I have installed locally. It builds successfully now